# Convert registry key HANDLE to HKEY

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using a mixed registry key functions environment (both `ntdll` and `advapi32` exported ones).
The problem I face is that the `ntdll` ones use the type `HANDLE` for a key handle, while the `advapi32` ones use `HKEY`.
I cannot figure out a syntax for converting `HANDLE` to `HKEY` in C++ and keep receiving compiler errors.

Comment: What are some examples of the functions you're trying to use? I wasn't aware that there were two registry APIs. Generally handles are an opaque type that *can't* be converted at all.

Comment: They're probably different because they probably can't be mixed between the two APIs. You might get away with just casting but I think it's safest not to try.

Comment: You are not supposed to use the ntdll functions.  Only the winapi functions have a guarantee that they'll remain stable across Windows versions.

Comment: I was trying to protect a key from deletion should it contain a specific value which is set by my main application.

Comment: I am hooking the NtDeleteKey function and then simply using (ntdll) NtEnumerateValueKey or (advapi32) RegEnumValue functions to check whether my protected value belongs to the key, in order to decline deletion. For both functions I receive ACCESS_DENIED error and I discovered that according to msdn both functions are denied in case calls as "delete" or "rename" are done in the same process (which is exactly my case :-))... I'm exploring now different functions that might do the job (like NtQueryMultipleValueKey) but the doc and samples are quite limitted... Many thanks for your helping hand!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to convert.  An `HKEY` is already a `HANDLE`.

winnt.h:

```
#ifdef STRICT
typedef void *HANDLE;
#if 0 && (_MSC_VER > 1000)
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__; typedef struct name##__ *name
#else
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name
#endif
#else
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) typedef HANDLE name
#endif
```

windef.h:

```
DECLARE_HANDLE(HKEY);
```

If you are getting compiler errors, you likely have `STRICT` defined, which is meant to prevent APIs from mixing handle types.  When `STRICT` is defined, `HKEY` maps to `struct HKEY__*`.  When `STRICT` is not defined, `HKEY` maps to `HANDLE` instead.

Since you know that NTDLL's registry `HANDLE`s and ADVAPI32's `HKEY`s represent the same thing, just use them as-is, type-casting compiler errors away when passing a handle between the two registry APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help. I noticed your will to share your experience in an NtQueryValueKey case on another site :-) In the meantime I described the evolution of my case in one of the other threads.

Comment: No matter how true it may or may not be in the case of `HKEY`, you can't rely on this reasoning: `DECLARE_HANDLE` is used for all kind of handle types that have nothing to do with "Handle to a kernel object" (`HANDLE`). Case in point: `HWND`, which is a handle to a USER object.

Answer (score 1):

Both `HANDLE` and `HKEY` represent kind of *opaque* values.

To *"convert"* from `HANDLE` to `HKEY`, just use a proper type cast like **`static_cast<>`**, e.g.:

```
#define STRICT
#include <Windows.h>

int main() 
{
    HANDLE h = nullptr;
    HKEY hKey = nullptr;

    // Use C++-style cast from HANDLE to HKEY:
    hKey = static_cast<HKEY>(h);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. I really appreciate it.